# how to install tomcat on windows

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Is there any link where i can download the exe file to install tomcat.

could not find it

what configuration i need to do so that it work with eclispe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to run an install for tomcat, it is pure java.  Here are the basic steps:

1. Install the appropriate JDK (JRE is not enough).  For tomcat 7.0 this is probabaly Java 6.
2. Set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the directory into which you installed the Java JDK.
3. Download Tomcat.
4. Unzip Tomcat.
5. If the directory into which you unzipped Tomcat is not the location from which you want to run Tomcat, move the unzipped directory tree to the desired location.
6. Set the CATALINA_HOME environment variable to the directory that contains the unzipped Tomcat files.
7. /cheer.  Tomcat is now installed.

Check out this link: [Tomcat Introduction](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

http://mirror.candidhosting.com/pub/apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.8/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.8.exe

Just set up a new server in Eclipse preferences and point it to your Tomcat install directory (by default it's C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0 or something similar).